# Mysql doesn't use index in queries with offsets

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple database with large amount of rows.

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl`(
    `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `name` NCHAR(50) NOT NULL
    ... other fields ...
  ) Engine=innodb;
```

I want to make paging imitation. And I know that classic offset is slow operation. Thats why I tried a trick from this [website](http://devoluk.com/mysql-limit-offset-performance.html)

My version of query is

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl` JOIN (SELECT id FROM `tbl` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000000, 100) as b on `b`.`id` = `tbl`.`id`;
```

but the trick wasn't effective. The query works extremely slow, because mysql still reads all `1000000` lines.

And even separated inner query works witn primary keys only, but doesn't use a b-tree.

```
SELECT id FROM `tbl` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000000, 100
```

So, why mysql engine doesn't use primary index when this query is totally covered with it?

Also I can't use `where id > SOME_NUMBER` condition because my table is very sparsed, and i don't know boundary ids of random page that was requested by user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following, where I force 2.2M rows into a table

### Schema

```
create table tbl
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    thing int not null
)engine=MyISAM;

insert tbl(thing) values (7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7),(7);

insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
insert into tbl(thing) select thing from tbl;
```

### The Counts

```
select count(*) as theCount,max(id) as theMax,min(id) as thMin from tbl;
+----------+---------+-------+
| theCount | theMax  | thMin |
+----------+---------+-------+
|  2228224 | 2228224 |     1 |
+----------+---------+-------+
```

### Query A (yours, uses a derived table)

```
explain 
SELECT *  
FROM `tbl` 
JOIN 
(SELECT id FROM `tbl` ORDER BY id LIMIT 1000000, 100) as b 
on `b`.`id` = `tbl`.`id`;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL    | NULL    | NULL | 1000100 | NULL        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | tbl        | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | b.id |       1 | NULL        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tbl        | index  | NULL          | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 2228224 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

### Query B (not a derived table)

```
explain 
SELECT t1.*  
FROM tbl t1 
JOIN tbl t2 
on t2.id = t1.id 
where t2.id>1000000 
limit 100 
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type   | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                | rows    | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | range  | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL               | 1195836 | Using where; Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | so_gibberish.t2.id |       1 | NULL                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+---------------+---------+---------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+
```

For those not familiar with using `Explain`, see a write-up I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13368211)

Comment: Does main distinction of Query B is "where"-condition insread of "offset"? As I mentioned, I don't know boundary ids. So, I haven't id for substitution in condition, if user requires random pages, not sequential ones. Anyway your answer helped to realize much complex solution, thank you.