# Subqueries vs join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Why use join since you can get the data from different table like using the subqueries below?

[image]

Comment: In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster.

Comment: Please don't use images for textual data.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577174/join-vs-sub-query?rq=1

Comment: wrote this up today showing **explain** results, similar, derived tables [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32747842)

Answer (score 1):

If you will use EXPLAIN then you will see the difference it makes when you are using sub queries and when you are using JOINS. JOINS are comparatively faster in most of the cases.

Here is a good article on [JOINs vs Subqueries](http://www.chrislondon.co/joins-vs-subqueries/)

> In JOINs RDBMS can create an execution plan that is better for your
>   query and can predict what data should be loaded to be processed and
>   save time, unlike the sub-query where it will run all the queries and
>   load all their data to do the processing.

See the test performed in the article:

[image]

> I added 100,000 businesses and 150,000 messages (random types for
>   random businesses).
>
> **Method 1: JOIN** I believed for the longest time that JOINs were faster than subqueries so I first tried this method. (Note: I had to
>   set SET SQL_BIG_SELECTS=1; just to even get the query to run… bad
>   sign!).
>
> ```
> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE b.id, b.name
> FROM `businesses` b
> LEFT JOIN `business_messages` bm ON
>     b.id = bm.business_id
>     AND bm.type = 'action'
> WHERE
>     bm.type IS NULL
> LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> **Method 2: Subquery** in WHERE This method was sent to me by my cousin. It’s a lot easier to read and understand what the query is
>   trying to do:
>
> ```
> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name 
> FROM businesses b 
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (
>     SELECT 1 
>     FROM business_messages 
>     WHERE business_id = b.id 
>         AND type = 'action'
> ) 
> LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> **Method 3: Subquery in JOIN** This is an idea I had after seeing the subquery in action:
>
> ```
> SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE id, name 
> FROM businesses b 
> LEFT JOIN (
>     SELECT business_id, type 
>     FROM business_messages 
>     WHERE type = 'action' 
>     GROUP BY business_id
> ) bm 
>     ON bm.business_id = b.id 
> WHERE bm.type IS NULL 
> LIMIT 10;
> ```
>
> **Results**
>
> ```
>   Method 1    Method 2    Method 3
> 1 5.51s   3.91s   0.41s
> 2 6.60s   4.74s   0.36
> 3 7.68s   2.40s   0.64s
> 4 4.23s   2.63s   0.36s
> 5 6.71s   2.06s   0.30s
> 6 5.23s   2.01s   0.53s
> 7 4.03s   2.80s   0.43s
> 8 4.56s   2.44s   0.55s
> 9 7.13s   1.95s   0.80s
> 10    7.04s   1.38s   0.43s
> Average   5.872s  2.632s  0.481s
> ```

Comment: so I should avoid sub quires? I'm new to mysql, my teacher taught sub queries before joins so I kinda confused now.

Comment: @AliceXu:- I will not say to `avoid` it but yes you can prefer using JOINS whenever you find that the same query can be written using JOINS.

Comment: The article directly contradicts your conclusion.

Comment: Notice that in option 3, the GROUP BY limits the results of the subquery before joining. It reduces the row count of the subquery to 1 row per business instead of 1 row per message.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use execution plan, you will see the difference. It is always best to use `JOIN` than using sub query when it comes to optimization, because sub query may take too much execution time especially when you are handling a large amount of data.