# Mysql GROUP BY with guaranteed dataset

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct, having

Hiho,
 i got following table:

```
+----+----+-------+----------+
| p1 | p2 | value | position |
+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |  5 |     0 |        1 |
|  1 |  6 |     0 |        2 |
|  1 |  7 |     0 |        3 |
|  1 |  7 |     1 |        4 |
|  1 |  8 |     1 |        5 |
+----+----+-------+----------+
```

as result of a query in need exactly this result:

```
+----+----+-------+----------+
| p1 | p2 | value | position |
+----+----+-------+----------+
|  1 |  5 |     0 |        1 |
|  1 |  6 |     0 |        2 |
|  1 |  7 |     1 |        4 |
|  1 |  8 |     1 |        5 |
+----+----+-------+----------+
```

As you will notice the dateset with the same p1 and p2 combination must be grouped, but i need the dataset with the highest position value. This behavior must be guaranteed.

I have tried something like:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
GROUP BY p1, p2
HAVING MAX(position)
```

without a proper result.
Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: nicely worded question

Answer (score 1):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/499b3/3

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t
LEFT JOIN `table` t1
ON t.p1 = t1.p1
  AND t.p2 = t1.p2
  AND t.position<t1.position
WHERE t1.p1 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this.  Here's one option using aggregation in a subquery:

```
select t.*
from yourtable t
   join (select p1, p2, max(position) maxposition
         from yourtable
         group by p1, p2) t2 on t.p1 = t2.p1 
                            and t.p2 = t2.p2
                            and t.position = t2.maxposition
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff2c3/3)

Comment: problem might be on the `explain` of it as compared to Alex's. Depending on actual schema.

Comment: @Drew -- yeah, there are a lot of different ways to do this.  Other databases make it a lot easier in my opinion.  Alex's revised answer will definitely work as well (and should be more efficient than `not exists`).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RESULT.* 
         FROM resultset RESULT 
              INNER JOIN 
              (SELECT p1,p2,value,(MAX(position)) AS position
               FROM resultset GROUP BY p1, p2) AS T2
              ON RESULT.p1=T2.p1 AND RESULT.p2= T2.p2 AND RESULT.position=T2.position
```

This will work fine

Comment: it is a problem with a subquery optimization

Comment: yes you did, t2, derived as it may be. See [Explain](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13368211/1816093)