# mysql query need optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, subquery

The below query is taking almost 14 secs to complete. I have a person table with 1M entries in it. Can anyone suggest me how to make the query faster and reduce the execution time to say something like 1, 2 or 3 seconds ? I am attaching the explain details below.

```
SELECT p.id, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN p.active=1 THEN 1 END) AS active_users_count, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =     DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS today_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =    DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS     yesterday_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END)         AS month_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     year_install_count, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     week_install_count, 
COUNT('x') AS total_users_count
FROM person p 
WHERE p.app_id IN (SELECT p2.id FROM project p2 ) GROUP BY p.app_id
```

239 row(s) returned

Execution Time : 13.504 sec
Transfer Time  : 0.001 sec
Total Time     : 13.505 sec

shw create table for person and project

```
person  CREATE TABLE `person` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_push_token` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `since_last_login` datetime NOT NULL,
  `platform` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  `hwid` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `app_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `since_last_push` datetime NOT NULL,
  `no_of_pushes` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `language` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `since_last_hour_push` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hwid` (`hwid`,`app_id`),
  KEY `fk_person_platform` (`platform`),
  KEY `fk_person_project` (`app_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_platform` FOREIGN KEY (`platform`) REFERENCES `platform` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_person_project` FOREIGN KEY (`app_id`) REFERENCES `project` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1310384 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


project CREATE TABLE `project` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_id` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `name` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description` longtext,
  `ios_configure` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `android_configure` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `freq_push` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hour_push` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `push_sent` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `push_opened` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
  `version` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `created_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `project_apprater` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `status` bigint(20) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_id` (`unique_id`),
  KEY `fk_project_ios_config` (`ios_configure`),
  KEY `fk_project_android_config` (`android_configure`),
  KEY `fk_project_freq_push` (`freq_push`),
  KEY `fk_project_hour_push` (`hour_push`),
  KEY `fk_project_apprater` (`project_apprater`),
  KEY `fk_project_platform` (`type`),
  KEY `name` (`status`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_android_config` FOREIGN KEY (`android_configure`) REFERENCES `project_configure_android` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_apprater` FOREIGN KEY (`project_apprater`) REFERENCES `project_apprater` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_freq_push` FOREIGN KEY (`freq_push`) REFERENCES `freq_push` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_hour_push` FOREIGN KEY (`hour_push`) REFERENCES `hour_push` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_ios_config` FOREIGN KEY (`ios_configure`) REFERENCES `project_configure_ios` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_project_platform` FOREIGN KEY (`type`) REFERENCES `platform` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `name` FOREIGN KEY (`status`) REFERENCES `project_status` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=313 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY p   index   \N  fk_person_project   8   \N  1158770 Using where
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY  p2  unique_subquery PRIMARY PRIMARY 8   func    1   Using index
```

**Updated Full Query**

```
SELECT 
  p3.id AS id,
  COALESCE(pug.active_users_count, 0) AS userCount, 
  p3.unique_id AS uniqueId,
  p3.name,
  p3.description,
  DATE_FORMAT(p3.created_date, '%m-%d-%Y %T') AS createdDate,
  p3.android_configure AS androidConfigure,
  p3.ios_configure AS iosConfigure,
  (SELECT 
    fp.active 
  FROM
    freq_push fp 
  WHERE fp.id = p3.freq_push) AS freqActive,
  (SELECT 
    hp.active 
  FROM
    hour_push hp 
  WHERE hp.id = p3.hour_push) AS hourActive,
  COALESCE(pug.total_users_count, 0) AS totalUserCount,
  COALESCE(pug.today_install_count, 0) AS todayInstallCount,
  COALESCE(pug.yesterday_install_count, 0) AS yesterdayInstallCount,
  COALESCE(pug.month_install_count, 0) AS monthInstallCount,
  COALESCE(pug.year_install_count, 0) AS yearInstallCount,
  COALESCE(pug.week_install_count, 0) AS weekInstallCount,
  (SELECT 
    plat.name 
  FROM
    platform plat 
  WHERE plat.id = p3.type) AS project_type ,
  ps.name
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    p.app_id,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN p.active = 1 
        THEN 1 
      END) AS active_users_count,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN DATE(p.created_date) = CURDATE() 
        THEN 1 
      END
    ) AS today_install_count,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN DATE(p.created_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
        THEN 1 
      END
    ) AS yesterday_install_count,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(
          CURDATE(),
          INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY
        ) 
        AND CURDATE() 
        THEN 1 
      END
    ) AS month_install_count,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR) 
        AND CURDATE() 
        THEN 1 
      END
    ) AS year_install_count,
    COUNT(
      CASE
        WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND CURDATE() 
        THEN 1 
      END
    ) AS week_install_count,
    COUNT('x') AS total_users_count 
  FROM
    person p 
    INNER JOIN project p2 
      ON p.app_id = p2.id 
  GROUP BY p.app_id) AS pug 
  RIGHT JOIN project p3 
    ON p3.id = pug.app_id     
  INNER JOIN project_status ps  
  ON p3.status = ps.id
ORDER BY userCount DESC,
  createdDate DESC
```

Comment: show output from `show create table person` and output from `show create table project`

Comment: or just do a join and no correlated subquery

Comment: you're comparing derived values. there is NOTHING you can do to optimize this until you start using bare indexed "original" values. plus, why `date_format(...)` to convert a date/time value from datetime->string->date, when you could simply have `date()` and go datetime->date directly?

Comment: where were those "I am attaching the explain details below". Here is how to [Share those](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13368211), seen under General Comments and sharing

Comment: Hi Drew, Pasted show create table person and project. Please check

Comment: A million persons?  Maybe the table name is not deceptive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revamping this Answer from previous version. Basically **Mark B** is right in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33482102/mysql-query-need-optimization/33501369?noredirect=1#comment54749145_33482102) under question. Fortunately progress has been made by the OP, and the time has been reduced from say 13 seconds to a bit under 6. The OP said (in comments under his own Answer and in chat) that if the time could be reduced to under 1 second, he would consider other approaches. Like the one I was talking about with him concerning accepting somewhat stale metrics where he gets to choose how long the stale duration lasts. A trade-off between staleness and speed for user.

So here is one approach to that.

One uses [Create Event](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) to create an event that fires automatically every nnn (time period) `Interval` of his choosing. That event updates a table that his end-users access. The event itself runs his query from his Answer that you will see embedded in the event below.

### Schema Change

```
create table appIdMetrics
(   -- this is the table Users hit against
    appId int not null primary key,
    active_users_count int not null,
    today_install_count int not null,
    yesterday_install_count int not null,
    month_install_count int not null,
    year_install_count int not null,
    week_install_count int not null,
    total_users_count int not null
);

create table evt_appIdMetrics
(   -- this is the worktable that only the Event uses
    -- while it puts together the refreshed data
    -- perhaps once every 5 minutes
    appId int not null primary key,
    active_users_count int not null,
    today_install_count int not null,
    yesterday_install_count int not null,
    month_install_count int not null,
    year_install_count int not null,
    week_install_count int not null,
    total_users_count int not null
);
```

### Event Creation

```
drop event updateAppIdMetrics;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE EVENT updateAppIdMetrics
    ON SCHEDULE
        EVERY 5 MINUTE

DO BEGIN
    truncate table evt_appIdMetrics;    -- this is the table that only the evt has access to

    -- time to refresh this table (approx 6 seconds)
    -- 280 rows (count as per OP comments)
    insert into evt_appIdMetrics
    (appId,active_users_count,today_install_count,yesterday_install_count,
    month_install_count,year_install_count,week_install_count,total_users_count)
    select p.app_id, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN p.active=1 THEN 1 END) AS active_users_count, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date)= CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS today_install_count,  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) THEN 1 END) AS     yesterday_install_count,  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END)         AS month_install_count,  
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     year_install_count, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     week_install_count, 
    COUNT('x') AS total_users_count
    FROM person p 
    INNER JOIN project p2 ON p.app_id = p2.id 
    GROUP BY p.app_id;

    -- BEGIN LOCK (important)
    -- figure out a locking scheme (work-in-progress, not completed yet)
    truncate table appIdMetrics;    -- this is the table users access

    -- the following should take a split second on the approximately 280 rows (count as per OP comments)
    insert into appIdMetrics
    (appId,active_users_count,today_install_count,yesterday_install_count,
    month_install_count,year_install_count,week_install_count,total_users_count)
    select appId,active_users_count,today_install_count,yesterday_install_count,
    month_install_count,year_install_count,week_install_count,total_users_count
    from evt_appIdMetrics;
    -- complete locking schema (work-in-progress, not completed yet)
    -- END LOCK (important)
END;$$
DELIMITER ;
-- evt creation succeeded by passing Syntax Error check
```

Users interact with table `appIdMetrics`. When I get a chance I will tweak the locking scheme mentioned. The UX for the user should be a split second. Data refresh interval is adjustable by OP for stale factor. From my experience the event will fire for the first time *after* the first time period interval. So that means 5 minutes.

I will provide a link for Event management in a little bit. **Edit**: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32508935) it is. Events must be enabled.

Comment: I will try this and let you know

Comment: Even after creating this covering index ( ALTER TABLE person ADD INDEX app_id_created_date_id ( app_id,created_date,id ) ) and with inner query, no improvement. Its still taking 10 secs

Comment: Drew, please see my answer, Replacing DATE_FORMAT() with DATE() ended the query execution time in 5 secs. Could you explain why there is a drastic improvement in performance?

Comment: the runtime optimation a.k.a. O(n) of date() is superior to date_format() due to less functionality in the former, but just enough functionality to make it right

Comment: Drew, Lock and Unlock are not allowed in stored procedures. what to do ?https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

Comment: Can we use GetLock() and ReleaseLock() for this ?

Comment: Mysql manual page on [Lock modes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-lock-modes.html)

Comment: Drew, can you suggest a locking feature...?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to join the table. But I'm not sure this can reduce the execution time until 3 seconds.

```
 SELECT p.id, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN p.active=1 THEN 1 END) AS active_users_count, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =     DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS today_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =         DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS     yesterday_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN    DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END)         AS month_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     year_install_count, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     week_install_count, 
 COUNT('x') AS total_users_count
 FROM person p 
 INNER JOIN project p2 ON p.app_id = p2.id 
 GROUP BY p.app_id
```

Comment: this query is taking 10 secs Wilianto. 3 secs improvement

Answer (score 0):

IN this query what I understood is, you need all the counts from last one year and not bothered about very old data. In that case,if you have a project_date in your project table then you can limit ids in sub query, this may help to perform much better than the old one.

```
SELECT p.id, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN p.active=1 THEN 1 END) AS active_users_count, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS today_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') =DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY), '%Y-%m-%d') THEN 1 END) AS yesterday_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS month_install_count,  
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS year_install_count, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE_FORMAT(p.created_date,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS week_install_count
FROM person p 
WHERE p.app_id IN (SELECT p2.id FROM project p2 AND p2.project_date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR)) 
GROUP BY p.app_id;
```

Now You can take the total count of each project Id seperately and merge with the above counts.

```
SELECT p.id, COUNT('x') AS total_users_count 
FROM person p 
WHERE p.app_id IN (SELECT p2.id FROM project p2) 
GROUP BY p.app_id;
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

The below query execution time reduced to 5 secs. Can you guys explain why changing from DATE_FORMAT() TO DATE() gives this drastic improvement ?

```
SELECT p.app_id, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN p.active=1 THEN 1 END) AS active_users_count, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date)= CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS today_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) = DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 DAY)) THEN 1 END) AS     yesterday_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL DAY(LAST_DAY(NOW())) DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END)         AS month_install_count,  
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 YEAR) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     year_install_count, 
 COUNT(CASE WHEN DATE(p.created_date) BETWEEN     DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND CURDATE() THEN 1 END) AS     week_install_count, 
 COUNT('x') AS total_users_count
 FROM person p 
 INNER JOIN project p2 ON p.app_id = p2.id 
 GROUP BY p.app_id
```

Comment: the runtime optimation a.k.a. O(n) of date() is superior to date_format() due to less functionality in the former, but just enough functionality to make it right

Comment: I want to make it below 2 secs. creating a covering index like (created_date, app_id, id ) didn't help. I thought it would give improvement, but no improvement at all even after creating this index. Do you know why ?

Comment: I want to group by application identifier and not by person identifier. I want to get the count of people belongs to each application. That's why app_id.

Comment: Okay, sorry, it is actually SELECT p.app_id, and not id

Comment: Please see the updated full query. Its taking 5.79 secs....Please check if there is anything wrong in it. Is it possible to make any more improvement in that query ? could it be possible to make it less than 3 secs ?

Comment: How accurate does it need to be, roughly. Accurate up to the last 5 minutes if it performs amazing for you ? And how many rows does it return, like 239 ? I forget.

Comment: It returns 281 rows, taking 5.790 secs for execution. Accurate up to the last 5 minutes ? what is it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94280/discussion-between-arun-and-drew).

Answer (score 0):

Another optimization thought...  In a subquery, compute *once* how many days ago `created_date`, as an integer.  Then in the outer query do the more efficient

```
age <= 365 AS year_install_count,
age <=   7 AS weel_install_count,
...
```

Note that `x <= y` is a "Boolean", which displays as "1" for true and "0" for false.  So, no need for repeated `DATE_SUB`, `DATE_FORMAT` or later `COALESCE`, etc.

For getting `age`, try `DATEDIFF(created_date, CURRDATE)` or play with `TO_DAYS(CURRDATE()) - TO_DAYS(CURRDATE())`.  Caveat: it may be off by 1.