# Is there a faster or better way to query for rows using a MySQL IN statement with many thousands of IDs returning many large TEXT fields?

Tags: mysql, select

Is there a more appropriate or faster way to do the equivilant of the following query in MySQL? The table I'm querying has billions of rows and some of the fields I pull are large `TEXT` fields. Something still seems slow about it to me though. Just going on a hunch.

```
SELECT field1, field2, fieldn
FROM table
WHERE data_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,10,42,420,666,...);
```

`data_id` has a non-unique index on it and actual query time is very fast (hundreds of milliseconds).

Could this be a disk issue because I'm essentially pulling random `TEXT` fields from a table that can't possibly be in memory? Any way to address that?

Could this be a network/communication issue simply because I'm returning thousands of full pages of text in some of these fields?

Thoughts / Suggestions / Questions?

Comment: what does explain say, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13368211) under General Comments and Sharing

Comment: What are you using to fetch the data, and how exactly are you measuring the performance?