# Having vs Where for Correlated SubQuery in MySQL

Tags: mysql, where-clause, correlated-subquery, having-clause

In finding some results I've found following two ways, but unable to decide which query has better performance. Hope someone will suggest!

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relavance FROM members m WHERE m.status = 1 AND m.membership > 1 AND (SELECT count(media_id) FROM arts AS media WHERE media.active = 1 AND media.owner = m.mem_id) > 0 AND MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ORDER BY relavance DESC, m.firstname ASC, m.lastname ASC

SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, (SELECT count(media_id) FROM arts AS media WHERE media.active = 1 AND media.owner = m.mem_id) AS arts_count, MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relavance FROM members m WHERE m.status = 1 AND m.membership > 1 AND MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) HAVING arts_count > 0 ORDER BY relavance DESC, m.firstname ASC, m.lastname ASC
```

**Edit:**

I've found another way too, now comparison is between three queries. Following is the new query which I've found and from all three queries which is the better in performance point of view ?

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS relavance FROM members m LEFT JOIN (SELECT count(media_id) AS arts_count, owner AS ar_owner FROM arts GROUP BY media_id) AS ar ON ar.ar_ar_owner = m.owner WHERE m.status = 1 AND m.membership > 1 AND MATCH (m.firstname, m.lastname) AGAINST ('*keyword1* *keyword2* *keyword3*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND  ar.arts_count > 0 ORDER BY relavance DESC, m.firstname ASC, m.lastname ASC
```

**Objective of the Queries:** To find users for matching keywords and having at-least one uploaded image/art and some more checks finally sort by relevance.

Comment: How about comparing execution plans for both?

Comment: check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13368211) and the sections General Comments and Sharing

Comment: A corellated sub query typically performs worse than an uncorellated one, so it's like asking whether a knife is better than a fork for eating soup